# Running PowerShell command to force stop processes via T-SQL (xp_cmdshell)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm having a problem running a PowerShell command in T-SQL via xp_cmdshell.

Below is the code I've been trying to run. The query does execute successfully, however it doesn't kill or force stop the process:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
DECLARE @PSCommand as varchar(1000) 
SET @PSCommand = 'powershell.exe -command "get-process chrome* | where{$_.CPU -gt 1} | kill -force"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @PSCommand
```

I'm suspecting it has to do with the account SQL server uses to execute cmd commands.

when trying to run whoami via TSQL:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

It returns:
nt service\mssqlserver

Is there anyway I can run the above PS command?

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` commands are run under the credentials of the Service Account that SQL Server is running under. The Server account you're using appears to be the built in with, which has minimal permissions, only those required to run SQL Server. If you need it to be able to have more "power" you'll need to create a service account.

Comment: I see. How do I go about creating a service account?

Comment: You're best speaking to your network administrator for that.

Comment: About that, I'm running this on a non-prod environment and SQL server installed locally on my machine. Do you have any sources where I can learn to do this? Thank you very much for answering my queries so far.